# Advantages of 64-bit CPU smartphone

Tags: encryption

> **Advantages of having a 64-bit CPU vs 32-Bit CPU smartphone**
>   …
>   3. **Complex Encryption. Improved Security**: 64-Bit can process incredibly large numbers allowing you to better encrypt data against unauthorized access.

<sup>source: http://www.amongtech.com/what-is-the-advantage-of-having-a-64-bit-smartphone/</sup>

Is the above statement correct, in particular with regards to the term *“complex encryption”*? I mean, how is the complexity increased with 64 bits? Is that related to the increase of the key size?

Comment: 32-bit ARM processors can already perform a large amount of 64-bit operations using NEON instructions. Having a native 64-bit processor will result in performance and efficiency improvements only. ARMv8 also has additional AES and SHA1/256 instructions that are separate from NEON and TrustZone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of marketing hype, that statement rates about a 9 in a scale from 0-10.

The reason is that we don't choose the encryption algorithm based on how many bits the CPU can handle at once.  Instead, we choose a secure algorithm, and then implement it using the resources that the CPU provides us.  There aren't any algorithms we cannot implement on a 32 bit CPU; hence a 64 bit CPU does not allow us to use new ones.

Now, there is a tiny kernel of truth there (and so doesn't rate a perfect 10 on the scale); sometimes a 64 bit CPU allows us to implement an algorithm more efficiently than a 32 bit CPU.  However, the delta is usually not large enough to influence an 'can-we-encrypt' decision.

Comment: Actually, there is probably a technical basis for that statement: ARMv8 processors introduce both 64-bit general registers and hardware acceleration for AES and SHA-{1,2}. But the two are not correlated.

Answer (score 6):

Saying that the large numbers you can handle with 64 bits allow for better encryption is misleading. 64 bits is too short for modern cryptographic algorithms.

Those algorithms which do rely on large numbers, need numbers much larger than 64 bits. For those, the computation have to be split up and processed in smaller parts. But being able to process 64 bits at a time rather than 32 means you can reduce the number of instructions needed by a factor of 2-4.

Symmetric algorithms, which don't work with large numbers but rather with multiple variables each sized conveniently for machine words, things may be different. For example the SHA2 algorithm can work with either 32 bit words (SHA-224 and SHA-256) or 64 bit words (all the other SHA2 variants). All the variants can be computed on both 32 and 64 bit CPUS. On a 32 bit CPU, the 32 bit variants are faster than the 64 bit variants. On a 64 bit CPU, the 64 bit variants are faster than the 32 bit variants.

In the end the most significant challenge to cryptography on a smartphone, is how the user can enter a password or a crypto key with sufficient entropy through the limited user interface. The type of CPU doesn't change that challenge at all.

Comment: would you please give the names for some of these modern cryptographic algorithms

Comment: I'm not sure about the correctness of the last statement. Normally a user should not have to enter a key directly, let alone a smartphone user.

Comment: @owlstead WPA-PSK is one example where a key might be entered directly by the user. (With the right software installed an Android phone can enter the key via a QR code instead). The point isn't so much, whether what the user enters is called a password or a key. The point is, that the entropy of what the user enters is all that stands between the user's data and an adversary with physical access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. When large bit-wise operations are used in cryptography, they are normally decomposed into byte[], not int32[].  Prime-modulus PK operations are done with large number libraries, on 2048 bits, so again, there is no real advantage to a 64 bit architecture over a 32 bit architecture.

Further, the problem with encryption was never speed. Encryption algorithms are plenty fast enough to run on existing 32 bit architectures with no perceptible performance degradation.

The real problem in the mobile market is that most app vendors (around 70% on Android) don't bother to use encryption - at all.  Unfortunately, that includes  popular apps like Outlook, many games, etc.

Comment: There's a real performance advantage when doing PK operations on 64-bit platforms. Big integer addition requires half as many instructions, and multiplication requires about 1/4 as many instructions compared to 32-bit.

Comment: Re: `… that includes popular apps like WhatsApp, …` – What on Earth makes you think WhatsApp doesn’t bother to use encryption? That’s plain wrong! Let me quote their website for your information: [*“WhatsApp communication between your phone and our server is encrypted. Even though data sent through our app is encrypted, remember that if your phone or your friend's phone is being used by someone else, it may be possible for them to read your WhatsApp messages. Please be aware of who has physical access to your phone. Cheers, WhatsApp Support Team”*](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/21864047)

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I had heard somewhere it was not encrypted.

Comment: Since you’re editing your answer anyway, you might also want to think twice about mentioning `Outlook`. Again, pointing to the related site: [*“Outlook Help: Encrypt e-mail messages”*](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/encrypt-e-mail-messages-HP001230536.aspx). Generally, you might want to do some research before claiming things about programs like WhatsApp and Outlook that clearly show you don’t know what those programs “can” or “can not” do… that doesn’t help! Btw: do you have any source to back up your `around 70% on Android`? After that many wrong claims, I just have to ask…

Comment: http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/mobile-apps/323918-outlook-com-s-android-app-does-not-encrypt-files-why-aren-t-you

Comment: When I Googled, I found this: [July 23, 2014 – “Software maker Microsoft Corporation responded positively to the findings. They assured that the company is committed to protecting the confidentiality and security of the personal information users store on their devices. **The company suggested that users of the Android app configure the required settings in their mobile phone device, to encrypt their emails or attachments.**”](http://windowsoutlookhelp.com/outlook-setting-2/outlook-for-android-apps-security-problems-exposed/) Looks like @e-sushi has a point there.